# WinRT ListView UI Virtualization and DataTemplateSelector with a lot of templates (10-15)

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I need to display ListView with different items (in total 10-15 item types). For this I use DataTemplateSelector. But this causes ListView odd behavior during scrolling: at some point it jumps to the top of list view. I've found this article for UWP: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-gridview-and-listview. It says that ItemTemplateSelector supports only 5 DataTemplates

> Additionally, an item template selector only considers five possible candidates when evaluating whether a particular container can be reused for the current data item.

I think this is the reason. I've tried to reduce the number of DataTemplates returned by my DataTemplateSelector and it solved the issue: scrolling works as expected. But how can I solve this issue without reducing number of DataTemplates? I know that I can disable virtualization, but I would like to keep it enabled if possible.

For UWP there is an option to use ChoosingItemContainer event, but it isn't available for WinRT.

Is it possible to solve this issue without disabling UI virtualization in WinRT?

Comment: Do you really need 10-15 different datatemplates? Keep in mind that in your datatemplate you can set visiblity of the panel and controls, so for example you can have only one ItemTemplate that shows different informations based on the current datacontext of each row.

Comment: Yes. It's something like questionnaire with different input controls: text, datepicker, checkbox, combobox, radiobuttons, tables, etc... ViewModels could have different logic (e.g. the way how answers are loaded and stored). So it's not good to mix it in one view model...

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing in my project (I have a listview with infinite scrolling). Basically, I did a part of virtualization myself.

I removed `DataTemplateSelector` completely. Instead, I use one template for all the items:

```
<ListView  
    ...
    >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <messages:MyCustomContainer />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Where `MyCustomContainer` is a simple UserControl:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyCustomContainer"
    ...
    DataContextChanged="OnDataContextChanged"
    >
    <Grid x:Name="Container"/>
</UserControl>
```

I instantiate and select appropriate nested template in code behind of `MyCustomContainer`:

```
void OnDataContextChanged(FrameworkElement sender, DataContextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var context = DataContext as MyModelThatHelpsDecideOnAppropriateVisualTemplate;

    if (context == null) {
        // this means, item has been removed from the list and cached (we call this 'virtualization')
        Container.Children.Remove(CurrentTemplate);
        ReleaseTemplate(CurrentTemplate); // clear and cache our concrete template
        CurrentTemplate = null;
    } else {
        // this means, we need to get a concrete template

        // ... some logic to decide on the proper visual template type
        Type templateType = GetTemplateTypeForData(context);

        // ... some logic to get visual template from cache
        CurrentTemplate = GetTemplateFromCache(templateType);

        Container.Children.Add(CurrentTemplate);
    }     
}
```

On the bright side, this works fine (does for me, and I have around a dozen item templates).

On the other side, this way the UI framework only virtualizes `MyCustomContainer` list items, and you have to cache concrete visuals yourself. In my example, you have to store instances of your 10-15 templates in some cache, and implement `GetTemplateTypeForData()`, `GetTemplateFromCache()` and `ReleaseTemplate()`... But that should be really straightforward, took around 100 lines of code for me.